How do I properly delete an object from a vector with a variable that matches what the user defines?
I'm trying to properly delete an object from a vector, if the object's user defined ID (stored in a variable) matches the ID the user wants to remove from the vector.
The code is here:
class Employee {
public:
    std::string empID, empName, empTitle, empHireDate, empSalary;
    Employee() {}
    // constructor
    Employee(string id, string name, string title, string hireDate, string salary) :
        empID(id),
        empName(name),
        empTitle(title),
        empHireDate(hireDate),
        empSalary(salary)
        {}

        //note, this is unneeded, ignore it.
        //returns the employee's ID
    string getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }
}

this code would be in main, ignore the else-if input statement, that's for a menu of options.
//command to delete an employee from the system
else if (input == "4") {
    cout << "Insert employee ID you wish to delete: ";
    cin >> input;
    //finds the employee, and deletes them from the vector
    for (Employee employees : Payroll) {
    if (input == employees.getEmpID()) {
        Payroll.erase(std::remove(Payroll.begin(), Payroll.end(), employees));
    }
}

As mentioned before, if the user has the proper ID and "employee" in the vector, I want to remove the employee from the vector.
When I compile the code, however, the compiler spits out a C2676 error originating from the Payroll.erase(std::remove(Payroll.begin(), Payroll.end(), employees)); line, more particularly the remove command.

binary'==': 'Employee' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator


I'd recommend std::erase_if... In your case, something like std::erase_if( Payroll, [id](const Employee& e) { return e.getEmpID() == id; } )

What is C2676? Can you post a complete and verbatim error message in a code block?

C2676 is binary'==': 'Employee' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Note: If you do it this way, I believe you should break out of the loop after finding and processing a match.

@DanielGowin Your comment seems to be an answer to your question. 'Employee' does not define operator==. Your use of std::remove requires this operator.

does the computer still remember where the place where the loop stopped?

@AviBerger where would the == go in the remove statement?

You are altering the vector in the loop. When you do that, the place where you might resume is no longer where you think it is.

remove has the use of == built in. But your Employee class doesn't have one and there isn't a predefined one that can work for it. So you need to provide a new one for Employee. This is called operator overloading Check out this post.

"ignore the else-if input statement" -- If the code is unimportant enough to ignore, then it is something you should remove from your [mre]. Code in a question should be example code, not necessarily real code. Think in terms of a short program that does nothing but demonstrate your issue. Something like: int main() { std::vector<Employee> Payroll /* Adding data to Payroll omitted */ Employee employees; Payroll.erase(std::remove(Payroll.begin(), Payroll.end(), employees)); } It doesn't matter that your intended functionality is gone; all that matters is reproing the issue.

"when I run the code, however, the Compiler spits out [...]" -- The compiler does nothing when you run the code. If it is the compiler producing the error message, then it occurs when you compile the code. (Many IDE's have a "compile & run" option. That is not the same as just running your program.) Can you confirm that it is the compiler giving the message?

yes, sorry, its when I compile and run the code is when I get the error. As for your first comment, i'll keep that in mind the next time I use Stack Overflow. I just copied the code directly from my source code, to here.

@DanielGowin "i'll keep that in mind the next time I use Stack Overflow." -- Why not this time? Your question does not die simply because you've solved your problem. The idea is that your question (and its answers) will live on to help the next person with the same question. There is still time to [edit] your question before you miss the opportunity to help that person. (The main requirement for editing your own question is that you not invalidate any existing answers. Otherwise, improve away.)

Employee does not implement operator==, which std::remove() uses to compare Employee instances. This is the reason for the compiler error.
You can implement operator== like this:
class Employee {
public:
    std::string empID, ...;
    ...

    bool operator==(const Employee &rhs) const {
        return empID == rhs.getEmpID();
    }
};

Alternatively:
class Employee {
public:
    std::string empID, ...;
    ...
};

bool operator==(const Employee &lhs, const Employee &rhs) {
    return lhs.getEmpID() == rhs.getEmpID();
}

Either way will fix the compiler error.

That being said, do note that you are also altering the std::vector while using a range-for loop to iterate it. The vector::erase() call will invalidate the iterator that the loop is using internally, causing undefined behavior.
You don't actually need the for loop at all. You can use std::remove_if() instead:
else if (input == "4") {
    cout << "Insert employee ID you wish to delete: ";
    cin >> input;
    //finds the employee, and deletes them from the vector
    Payroll.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            Payroll.begin(), Payroll.end(),
            [&](Employee &e){ return input == e.getEmpID(); }
        ),
        Payroll.end()
    );
}

Alternatively, in C++20 and later, you can use std::erase_if() instead, eg:
else if (input == "4") {
    cout << "Insert employee ID you wish to delete: ";
    cin >> input;
    //finds the employee, and deletes them from the vector
    std::erase_if(Payroll,
        [&](Employee &e){ return input == e.getEmpID(); }
    );
}

Either way will scan the whole vector removing all matching Employee objects, as your original code was trying to do.
However, if there will ever only be 1 Employee object with a matching ID, then there is no point in continuing the scan after a match is found. You should use std::find_if() instead, eg:
else if (input == "4") {
    cout << "Insert employee ID you wish to delete: ";
    cin >> input;
    //finds the employee, and deletes them from the vector
    auto iter = std::find_if(
        Payroll.begin(), Payroll.end(),
        [&](Employee &e){ return input == e.getEmpID(); }
    );
    if (iter != Payroll.end())
        Payroll.erase(iter);
}


I am a new programmer, currently in college for it, could you please explain to me how to properly implement operator ==? i tried the method Avi Berger mentioned about an hour ago.

@DanielGowin At some point in your code (maybe immediately after you define class Employee) add this operator definition bool operator==(const Employee& x, const Employee& y) { ... } Replace the ... with code that returns true of false depending on whether x and y are equal or not.

@DanielGowin The point is that you cannot say to the compiler 'remove this employee if it is equal that employee' without also telling the compiler what it means to say that two employees are equal to each other. That is what defining operator== does.

this was it, thank you @RemyLebeau
